# Is the half-full rule and full rule followed in the 6th and 7th periods?

Tags: electronic-configuration, transition-metals

Is the half-full rule and full rule followed in the 6th and 7th periods? (Note: Half-full rules is Hund's rule)

**Example:** What is the correct electron configuration?
$$\ce{W = [Xe] 6s^2 4f^{14} 5d^4}$$ doesn't use half full rule, or
$$\ce{W = [Xe] 6s^1 4f^{14} 5d^5}$$ uses half full rule.

Comment: Just a note: here at my place, it's more common to call it "fully-filled" instead of just "full".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer: no!** The first known exception to occur in the periodic table is in period 5:  niobium’s ground state electronic configuration is

> $\ce{Nb: [Kr] 5s^1 4d^4}$

which is not warranted by the “usual” rules for determining electronic configuration. So, the “half-full rule” is not sufficient in periods 5 and higher.

---

Let’s look at Wikipedia’s [list of exceptions to Madelung’s rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_configuration#Other_exceptions_to_Madelung.27s_rule). In period 4, the only exceptions are **$\ce{Cr}$** and **$\ce{Cu}$**, which are accounted for by the “half-full rule”. (Don’t bother too much about the dispute for [Ni](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nickel#Electron_configuration_dispute).)

In period 5, the exceptions to Madelung’s rule are classified in three groups:

- **$\ce{Mo}$** and **$\ce{Ag}$**: they are the analogues of **Cu** and **Cr**
- **$\ce{Pd}$** is $\ce{5s^0 4d^10}$: a different type of application of the explanation that *“fully filled shells are particularly stable”*, because in this case *two* electrons from the s shell were pulled into the d shell. Not what you usually learn.
- **$\ce{Nb}$** is $\ce{5s^1 4d^4}$,  and **$\ce{Ru}$** is $\ce{5s^1 4d^7}$: these cannot be explained by simple rules, and one has to perform complex quantum chemistry calculations to understand these electronic configurations.

Period 6 contains further inconsistencies, because of the introduction of $\ce{f}$ orbitals into the mix.

Comment: F'x, I'm sure this was just a slight oversight, but another important exception in period 5 is rhodium ($\ce{5s^1 4d^8}$), as given on that Wikipedia page. Also, a very important supplementary read: [How can one explain niobium’s weird electronic configuration?](//chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/2469)