# Is there a general method for working out electron configurations?

Tags: electronic-configuration

For up to period 3, elements' electron configurations are relatively easy to work out until the transition metals begin. Then some elements may have $\ce{4s}$ orbitals which are preferred by electrons over $\ce{3d}$ orbitals. These small rules don't make sense all the time and only cover some elements. Is their any *master* method for working out the electron configurations of *any* given element?

Comment: No, at least not by hand. The Aufbau Principle is only a guideline but in later elements many different effects are at play which are nearly impossible to consider without doing a thorough calculation. Maybe [this question](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/4332/189) is of interest to you.

Answer (score 2):

There is a semi-empirical method to fill the atomic orbitals: atomic orbitals are filled  in the order of increasing *n*+*l*. If the sum *n*+*l* is equal for two atomic orbitals, they are filled in order of increasing n.
This gives the following order for filling the orbitals:
1s, 2s, 2p, 3s, 3p, 4s, 3d, 4p, 5s, 4d, 5p, 6s, 4f, 5d, 6p, 7s, 5f, 6d, 7p, 8s, 5g, 6f, 7d, 8p, and 9s