# Electronic configuration of chromium(II)

Tags: electrons, electronic-configuration

> Which is the electron configuration for $\ce{Cr^2+}$
>
> (A) $\mathrm{[Ar]4s^23d^4}$
>   (B) $\mathrm{[Ar]4s^23d^2}$
>   (C) $\mathrm{[Ar]4s^03d^4}$
>   (D) $\mathrm{[Ar]4s^43d^2}$

---

I referred to the periodic table and got the orbital notation for $\ce{Cr}$ as $$\mathrm{[Ar]4s^23d^4}\tag1$$
So $\ce{Cr^2+}$ would be $\mathrm{[Ar]4s^23d^2}$, or (B). But the teacher counted that wrong and said it was actually (C).

> **Question:** Shouldn't the answer be (B)? Why does $\ce{Cr}$ *lose* the $\mathrm{s}$ shell first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chromium’s standard electron configuration as given by the aufbau principle is actually more of an exception than you may think initially. See for example [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/4332) to catch a small glimpse of the truth behind the simplifications.

The aufbau principle tells you to fill in the order $\ce{1s, 2s, 2p, 3s, 3p, 4s, 3d, 4p, }\dots$ That order, however, is only valid for *neutral* atoms (and not always as the linked question implies). As soon as you add charge to an atom, the relative orbital energies shift. The $\ce{3d}$ orbitals, belonging to the M shell, are stabilised more than the $\ce{4s}$ orbital which belongs to the N shell. This is a general rule: charges typically stabilise orbitals belonging to lower shells more than those in higher shells.

Thus, while in neutral chromium the $\ce{4s}$ and the $\ce{3d}$ shell are very close in energy, this balance completely tips towards $\ce{3d}$ (which then has a lower energy) upon oxidation. Therefore, one should always assume an empty $\ce{4s}$ orbital when discussing the electronic configuration of charged d-block elements.

Comment: Yup. I agree with this much more. Exchange energy, being a relatively small factor compared to orbital energies, should really always be the last-resort explanation when everything else doesn't work. And I once wrote a bit about the 3d vs 4s matter, so I'll dump this here: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/33310/16683