# How to calculate energy gap when determining electron configuration?

Tags: energy, electronic-configuration

The weird electron configuration of Niobium was well explained on this post:

[How can one explain Niobium’s weird electronic configuration?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2469/how-can-one-explain-niobium-s-weird-electronic-configuration)

It was pointed out that electrons fill orbitals with higher exchange energy and lower repulsion energy, only if the sum of the positive exchange energy and negative repulsion energy **overcomes the energy gap between orbitals**.

The only problem is that I do not know how to quantify the energy gap.

How can I calculate the energy gap between orbitals?

Comment: Long story short, you can't.

Comment: @IvanNeretin So would the value have to be taken out of a data booklet?

Comment: Basically, yes.

Answer (score 1):

You could calculate the energy of your initial electron configuration, then do the same for your final state and work out the difference. The Los Alamos Flexible Atomic Code (https://github.com/flexible-atomic-code/fac) can do that for you. There should be no state where you fill shells from the ground up that has a lower energy than what we now call the ground state of nobium.